# Confused by construction of socket instance and method call

Tags: python, python-3.x

I understand what socket does and why it exists. I just have an issue wrapping my mind around the code construction of it all. Take for example this code:

```
import socket
IP = 127.0.0.1
PORT = 7777
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((IP, PORT))
```

I can grasp we want to connect to localhost at 7777. I see we are making a variable called `s`. This variable is calling `socket.socket` and putting in two arguments that you have to provide arguments for. Now with the `s.connect` I have a hard time thinking about this.

I think it would be `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((IP, PORT))` in my head if there was no `s`. Correct? Does this mean the `socket.AF_INET` and `socket.SOCK_STREAM` arguments carry to the `s.connect`? Or are they stuck at `socket.socket`?

I understanding what is happening, I just don't get the structure. Can anyone help me grasp it better?

Comment: `socket.socket` returns an instance of `socket.socket`. If you don't save it to s, you won't be able use it later. I guess you would say that the arguments carry to `socket.connect()` because they define the type of `socket` being "connected".

Comment: "This variable is calling socket.socket". The variable isn't calling it.  The code calls `socket.socket(...)` and the reult is stored in `s`.  `s` now holds a "handle" to the socket, the result of `socket.socket(...)`.  So it's equivalent to `socket.socket(...).connect(...)` except you can refer to the socket

Comment: Did you notice the SyntaxError when you tried running that code?

Answer (score 2):

`socket.socket` is a class.  You are creating an object of type `socket.socket`.  Sockets are used for many things, so what follows next differs depending on your need.

So, after the object is created, you now have a generic socket that is designed for use in a TCP exchange.  Other parameters to the constructor produce sockets for other uses.

You then use the `connect` method, to decide to use your socket as the client end of a TCP connection.  If you go look at a C tutorial, you'll see that this pattern exactly matches the C pattern.  You create the socket, passing those two constants, then you `connect` or `bind`, depending on whether you are client or server.

As for

> I think it would be "socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((IP, PORT))" in my head if there was no s. Correct?

that would literally work, but you would not have stored the socket object anywhere, so you couldn't USE it.  `connect` does not return the socket, it returns a success/failure code.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

That line of code creates a specific *kind* of socket.  There are many different kinds of sockets.

```
s.connect((IP, PORT))
```

That line of code connects the socket to a specific address.

So, first you *create* a socket object and specify exactly what *kind* of socket it should be, and then you *connect* that socket to a specific address.

What is your confusion?